# How can I turn off Facebook IM permanently?

Tags: facebook, instant-messaging

Since I got a new google phone (G2) the facebook app has been running constantly. I turn it off and it still is running for some reason. Not a problem except that it always looks like I'm screwing around on Facebook and people send me IMs like "go to bed" or "hello? you aren't replying" etc. I don't like that people can just IM me any time they want and that my phone says I'm available on Facebook when I'm asleep or at work or whatever the case may be. (it looks like I'm unproductive)

There doesn't seem to be a way to turn off Facebook IM from my mobile device. Does anyone have any suggestions

Comment: Do you have Facebook for HTC Sense or the official Facebook for Android app?

Comment: the official app that came with my G2. It has a big widget on my home page as well.

Comment: If you have a widget on your home page, then that will always be running. You'll need to remove the widget to have a chance of getting the rest to stop.

Comment: I have the same problem and I've tried everything, even uninstalling the app on my android and still my stupid picture appears as "available on mobile" with a stupid cell phone icon next to my name..I'm gna delete my facebook..It got on my nerves already

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The newest version of the Facebook app does not include chat.  You can uninstall or disable the Facebook Messenger application to keep IM from running.

---

In the older official Facebook for Android app, you can shut off chat via the following:

1. Start up Facebook
2. Make sure you're in the main menu (press Back if it shows the news feed)
3. Click "Chat"
4. Press the Menu button and hit "Go Offline"

Comment: This works except that when I go back into chat it turns it back on. I wish facebook could just have an option where you don't see chat or when you click it, it should still be offline until I click "Go online" or something.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat Why do you need to go into chat when you don't want to chat? :P

Comment: @Matthew.. ha! Well, sometimes I don't want to chat, sometimes I do, when I *do*, I want to know that I have bee OFFLINE this whole time and be able to turn on chat and then see people popup green like any normal IM client would.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the FB messenger app installed on your Droid, go to the apps and open Messenger (FB blue app next to Messaging).  Press the menu button (the 4 small squares on front of Droid) and you should see the option to Log Out on the right.  Be careful, once you log out there it says Continue.  If you continue, it just logs you back in.  So, just leave it at that and go back to the App and Continue when you do want to be logged into FB chat.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I have noticed that you actually can't do this as well as it's supposed to work.

The **only** solution I have found is to uninstall the app. I know that many providers and manufacturers include Facebook as a "system app". I don't know why they have, but it means it's stuck there until you root or whatever.

You can logout of the Facebook app and either use m.facebook.com in a web browser or download an alternative like [FriendCaster for Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.senab.blueNotifyFree&hl=en). (I do not work for them, look for another if you don't like them).

Joe :)