# Is there any way to let Facebook run only when I want?

Tags: facebook, auto-start

Is there any way to let the Facebook app run only when I want to use it and really close it when i don't need it?

I've already disabled it with autostarts, moved to sd, yet it is still running 24/7.

I don't want to appear on the Facebook chat, also don't want to waste 30mb of ram, and of course there are no FB widgets on the home screen

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9181/how-can-i-turn-off-facebook-im-permanently which looks to be a similar question, but more focussed on the chat.

Comment: I suppose this is the one time when it would be okay to run a task-killer. I suspect it'd by like playing _Whack-A-Mole_, though, with the app constantly re-starting.

Comment: Did you turn off syncing for that account?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9181/how-can-i-turn-off-facebook-im-permanently

Comment: You do know that you can log out from the chat? Open the Facebook app, press Chat and then the menu button and "Go Offline"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With root, it's possible to use an app like [Ice Box](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catchingnow.icebox) to freeze the app and unfreeze it only when needed. It can be set up to freeze the app again when the phone goes to sleep. In this way the most invasive apps like Facebook, Instagram, will **only** run when the user want it. (Of course no notifications will appear)

Answer (score 1):

You could always install Titanium Backup (a GREAT app to have) or App Manager (was just released today by JRummy) and "Freeze"/"Unfreeze" the app when you want it to run or not run. This is a very quick/simple/painless operation and there's absolutely no chance for it to run (taking up resources or draining battery) while it's "Frozen" - it just takes up a bit of storage space is all.

Comment: I'll try that App Manager. If only they didn't translate from english using google translator... (i don't understand why developers are translating apps with google translator instead asking actual users to do that)

Answer (score 1):

As the person before me said, a good way to do it would be to install TitaniumBackup pro (it's a really great app, can't recommend it enough, and the market commenters seem to agree) and set up a label called facebook which only contains the face book app. Then, create 2 widgets (one that freezes on one that defrosts facebook). It's a bit clunky and takes up 2 home screen cells but it's guaranteed to work :)

Answer (score 0):

There's  an awesome  app called "Tinfoil  for Facebook" that offers all the benefits  of  FB without being so resource - consuming .  Link:  http://www.cnet.com/how-to/use-tinfoil-for-facebook-to-protect-your-privacy-on-android/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, 
it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here 
and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

[Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) prevents apps from running when they are not actively in use.  It works seamlessly without needing to manually freeze and unfreeze it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Force Quit?

You can always **force quit an app**:

1. Go to your settings
2. Scroll until you see App manager, Apps, Application Manager (You might need to go to general tab if your Android is not the old version)
3. Swipe left or right until you arrive at Running tab
4. Find Facebook app (or whatever app you are trying to force quit)
5. Press Force Quit on top.

Additional steps **(That will erase stored facebook's data on your phone)**:

6. Press Clear cache
7. Press Clear Data
8. Press Remove or Uninstall (Or Disable if it was installed with as system app)

Answer (score 0):

Use Greenify to cut off the wake up paths of the Facebook app after greenifying it. This is the best method I know.

Answer (score 0):

Use a modded android Facebook app. The version might differ from the ones in Google Playstore but at least you will still be able to have the same browsing Facebook experience. The best part is the modded Facebook App won't auto start itself unless you wanted it to.

Comment: Please add a link to one such official app from Play Store

Comment: https://apk4free.net/facebook-color-mod-messenger-apk/

Answer (score -1):

! This might be something too basic and obvious... But since this was happening to me too, you might be experiencing the same issue... When you press that square on the bottom right of your screen to visualise all the apps you have open, at the top right of your app window, there is a cross and a lock.. as seen in the image attached... The lock should be unlocked.. just click it to unlock it.  If it is locked, the app will never close.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0b4r.jpg)

Comment: i wanted exactly the opposite, to kill it when not on foreground, not making sure it kept open forever (which for facebook is never needed)